# Why am I being prompted for a variable which I already defined?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, dynamic

So, I am new to using PL/SQL. I have defined a variable called **startDate**, and then I want to refer to it later on in some queries. However, when I refer to it later on using *&&startDate*, I am being prompted for the variable.

```
/* Define the date bounds used */
/* Depending on the current quarter I want to set my start and end dates differently */
DROP TABLE DATE_BOUNDS;
CREATE TABLE DATE_BOUNDS AS
select
      case    when to_char(sysdate, 'Q') = '1' then to_date('10/01' || to_char(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')-1))
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'Q') = '2' then to_date('01/01/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))     
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'Q') = '3' then to_date('04/01/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'Q') = '4' then to_date('07/01/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))
      end as date1,
      case    when to_char(sysdate, 'Q') = '1' then add_months(to_date('10/01' || to_char(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')-1))-1,12)
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'Q') = '2' then add_months(to_date('01/01/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))-1    ,12) 
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'Q') = '3' then add_months(to_date('04/01/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))-1,12)
                  when to_char(sysdate, 'Q') = '4' then add_months(to_date('07/01/' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))-1,12)
      end as date2
from dual;

/* Defining the variable 'startDate' as 'date1' from the previous table */
DECLARE 
  startDate date;
BEGIN
  SELECT date1 INTO startDate
  FROM DATE_BOUNDS;
END;
```

When I try something simple, like:

```
select &&startDate from dual;
```

When I run this in SQL Developer, I am being prompted for the startDate instead of it just using what is *supposed* to be being defined in the **DECLARE** step... What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the PL/SQL `startDate` variable, which declared in and only exists inside your PL/SQL block, with an SQL*Plus or SQL Developer [substitution variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB). The latter if [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm) by the client and can be used inside an anonymous block (though it's unusual to do so). They are completely separate variables in different scopes, and are not interchangeable.

You can't see or refer to the PL/SQL variable outside the block. If you want something you can refer to easily on both you use a client [bind variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm#SQPUG133):

```
var startDate varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT to_char(date1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') INTO :startDate
  FROM DATE_BOUNDS;
END;
/

select :startDate, to_date(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

or

```
print :startDate
```

Three things to notice though. Firstly the references have a colon, `:startDate`, to indicate that it's a bind variable; there is now no local PL/SQL variable; and you can't have  date type so have to convert to and from dates, so this isn't the best example...

---

If you want to populate a substitution variable from a query, you can use [`column new_value`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#sthref1333), which is also a client command, without any PL/SQL:

```
column oldColName new_value newColName
SELECT to_char(date1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS oldColName
FROM DATE_BOUNDS;
```

You then refer to `&newColName`.

Comment: It is possible, but I don't remember the SQL*Plus commands, to create a bind variable in SQL*Plus. Assign value(s) to that variable in a PL/SQL anonymous block. And then use that value bind variable later, such as `select :startDate from dual`. One limitation is that the types were limited, `DATE` was not supported by SQL*Plus. (May have changed.)

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you.  However, I will later use the dates in **CREATE TABLE** statements - which do not allow bind variables as I just found out.  Oh well.

Comment: @mjavon - I've added a way to get a value fom a query, as a substitution variable, which you can then use in `create table`. or whatever. You'd need a different format mask though, without the dashes. Creating tables based on dates or any other data doesn't sound like a good data model, but that's another issue.